# Handlebars is not generating JSON from a Map<string,object> in Typescript

Tags: typescript, handlebars.js

I am trying to get Handlebars JS to display the contents of a Typescript Map where the keys are strings and values are objects.  Why doesn't the code and template below work?  The code is generating index numbers as keys (when it should be string keys) and empty values. How do I fix it?

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import Handlebars from 'handlebars';

function main() {
  let template;
  try {
    const content = fs.readFileSync('template.hbs').toString();
    template = Handlebars.compile(content);
  }
  catch (e) {
  }

  let map = new Map<string, object>();
  map.set("color1", { type: "red"});
  map.set("color2", { type: "green"});
  map.set("color3", { type: "blue"});

  console.log("JSON");
  let json = template({map}, { strict: true });
  console.log(json);
}

main();
```

and `template.hbs`

```
{
    "colors": {
    {{#each map}}
    "{{@key}}": {
        "type": "{{type}}"
    },
    {{/each}}
    }
}
```

OUTPUT is:

```
JSON
{"colors": {
    "0": {
        "type": ""
    },
    "1": {
        "type": ""
    },
    "2": {
        "type": ""
    },
}
}
```

Comment: Should be `{{this.type}}` instead of `{{type}}`?

Comment: Maybe but then why do the keys not display properly?

Comment: And no, this.type did not work either.

Comment: I would start by logging the value of `map` from the template to see what object you are dealing with `{{log map}}`.

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars can't handle a map directly.  It needs a helper method:

```
   Handlebars.registerHelper('jsonmap', function (context) {
      return JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(context), null, 2);
    });
```

The template then uses this handler:

```
{
    "colors": {{map}}
}
```